# Unable to run random programs!

Tags: 16.04, steam, minecraft

A month ago I installed Steam via the .deb file provided by them. After the installation the icon appeared on the desktop but I can not run it - whenever I click on it, it blinks yellow a few times and nothing more happens. The same happened today after I installed the new java-free launcher for Minecraft - a few blinks and nothing more.
OS 16.04, almost completely pure.

Comment: Try running from the command line,  it may shed some light by the logs on the issue.

Comment: It gave me a nice list of errors like "command not found", "no job control", "unexpected end of file", etc. This is what happened while trying to run Steam via terminal